# What is the parent argument for?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I read in the pyqt [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#QWidget) that if parent is None, the QWidget will become a window. But in my main widget I create several QWidget subclasses without passing the parent argument, and it works fine:

```
widget = MyWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(widget)
self.setLayout(layout)
```

How does this work, and what is the parent argument really for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setLayout`, the layout is automatically made a child of the widget to which it is assigned:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setLayout

Hence, what you have discovered doesn't seem to be an issue with `parent` in general, but a feature of `setLayout`. Note that `QLayout` is not a `QWidget`, so will never be made an independent window -- it is forced to sit there in memory waiting to be glued to a widget.